# getting 200 ok code but image not uploaded on twitter using codebird

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

i am using codebird-php to post images on twitter, when i do that i get 200 ok http code but the image is not uploaded. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('./src/codebird.php');
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('74AFitlDilqB2HlFQ8Cjszz6I', 'tDlVndY7iJG8loFGG1sq3gJaj59CwNx6UV5o6wEtV0LJebNJ0y'); // static, see 'Using multiple Codebird instances'

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$cb->setToken($access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
//$reply = $cb->statuses_update('status=Whohoo, I just again tweeted!');


// send tweet with these medias
$reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
    'media' => 'http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BilbaoGuggenheim_EN-US11232447099_1366x768.jpg'
));
print_r($reply);
?>
```

This is what i am getting on running it in my browser:

```
stdClass Object ( [media_id] => 540134777223790592 [media_id_string] => 540134777223790592 [size] => 179801 [image] => stdClass Object ( [w] => 1366 [h] => 768 [image_type] => image/jpeg ) [httpstatus] => 200 [rate] => )
```

PS: I am running it on localhost, tweeting text works but not image and i am using Abrahams oAuth for getting oAuth token.

Comment: @alda1234 i dont understand what shall i turn on and off? if u mean by logging out and in and authenticating again i have done that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by changing

```
$reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
    'media' => 'http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BilbaoGuggenheim_EN-US11232447099_1366x768.jpg'
));
```

to

```
$params = array(
  'status' => 'Auto Post on Twitter with PHP http://goo.gl/OZHaQD #php #twitter',
  'media[]' => 'http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BilbaoGuggenheim_EN-US11232447099_1366x768.jpg'
);

// send tweet with these medias
/*$reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
    'media[]' => "@http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BilbaoGuggenheim_EN-US11232447099_1366x768.jpg"
));*/
$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
```